# How can I programmatically insert UICollectionView into UITableViewCell ? [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

Does anyone know how to integrate a collectionView into the top section of a tableView? I'm trying to get a top section/row that has horizontally scrolling images, and other section/rows below it to just be normal  tableview rows. Like what you might see in an app like facebook messenger or tinder/bumble's matches/conversations page.

I understand how to produce UICollectionView and UITableView separately, but between the multiple functions/delegates/datasources, I can't figure out how to properly layer the code.

I am working programmatically rather than on storyboard. I know there are other posts on inserting UICollectionView in UITableViewCell, but they're either storyboard implementations, or on outdated versions of Swift - would be awesome if someone could do a run-through so that anyone looking in the future could also understand the logic even if some of the code becomes outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. declare collectionView in the TableViewCell swift file.

   `var viewPhotos: UICollectionView!`

   ```
   func reset(with cellData: CellData) {
        self.data = cellData
        viewPhotos.dataSource = self
        viewPhotos.delegate = self   
        viewPhotos.reloadData()
   }
   ```
2. in the `init` function or `awakeFromNib` check if photoCollectionView is initialized and add it to the cell.

> ```
> let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
>  layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal        
>  viewPhotos = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
>  viewPhotos.collectionViewLayout = layout
>  viewPhotos.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
>  viewPhotos.isPagingEnabled = true        
>  viewPhotos.register(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PhotoCollectionViewCell.cellIdentifier)
> ```

3. Add UICollectionView Datasource and Delegate To the UITableViewCell

> ```
> extension TableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {  
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,numberOfItemsInSection > section: Int) -> Int {
>     return photoUrls?.count ?? 0
> }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
>     let cell: PhotoCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhotoCollectionViewCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
>     
>     if let value = photoUrls {
>         cell.reset(with url: value[indexPath.row]);
>     }
>     return cell
> }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
>     return CGSize(width: kPhotoWidth, height: kPhotoHeight)
> }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt  section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
>     
>     return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
>     
> }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout > collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
>     return 0.0
> }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
>     return 0.0
> }
>
> }
> ```

4. PhotoCollectionViewCell

> create a PhotoCollectionViewCell derived from UICollectionViewCell
> and add a UIImageView, and make all edge constraints to 0 to the
> superview.   load UIImageView based on photoUrl.

Comment: where is collectionview delegate and datasource?

Comment: @ErkamKUCET, You can set the delegate and datasource in awakeFromNib method, or you can define a `reset` method like i did in step 1).

Comment: Okay, Thank you.